# How to redirect user and assign him the session that got created

Tags: java, spring, session, redirect, servlets

Consider below scenerio

A.com/security is the login application.Once the user is authenticated here he needs to be redirected to B.com/myapp application. B.com/myapp does not have any authentication logic,but it has a sessionfilter which checks for security token in the session if its not it will redirect to A.com/security.

I have researched on how to implement this and came to know Single sign on will be the best solution.

Keeping SSO implementation aside,can the below logic work.

Once User is authenticated in A.com/security,the security object(username,roles,token..) will be sent to B.com/myapp via rest api call.now in B.com/myapp we create a session and dump these values and return the sessionId as response. A.com/security uses this sessionId and redirects user to B.com/myapp with jsessionId.Is this approach correct?

Implementation issue - How to redirect user and assign him the session that got created.

Few of my tries below

Not Working

```
 @RequestMapping("home2/{sessionID}")
    public void redirect(@PathVariable String sessionID,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionID + "; Path=/myapp/; HttpOnly");
        response.sendRedirect("http://B.com/myapp/home");
    }
```

Working - But subsequent requests are not connected to this session(redirects back to login),dont know what i am missing here

```
@RequestMapping("home2/{sessionID}")
    public void redirect(@PathVariable String sessionID,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        response.sendRedirect("http://B.com/myapp/home;jsessionid="+sessionID);
    }
```